# Query, transpose and skip blank cells

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm completely lost here:

I have a table that looks like this, but has a variable amount of value columns

```
+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| name1      | value1     | value2    | value3    |
+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| name1      | value1     |           | value3    |
+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| name1      |            | value2    | value3    |
+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

What I need is a table looking like this:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| name1      | value1     | value2    | value3    |
+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| name1      | value1     | value3    |           |
+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| name1      | value2     | value3    |           |
+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

What I came up with for now is this formula, which only works for the first row of data. Named range is my source table range.

```
=MTRANS(QUERY(MTRANS({Named Range});"select * where Col1 is not null"))
```

I cannot just add all the columns to it, as I dont know how many of them will be. What secret sauce will I have to add to be able to solve this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Andii  This seems to do what you want:

```
=ArrayFormula(split(transpose(query(transpose(A5:D7),,9^99))," ",1,1))
```

I have a sample sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Em1V9o5aeAtq0Fo_Yb39xXAZRmIZhwSyAHawa-ExilA/edit?usp=sharing

Let us know if this answers your question.